# determining the time constant for KI from a Graph

Tags: pid-controller

I'm having the following graph, I'm using PI controller, so I used a gain of KP = 2048.

I would like to determine the KI from that graph and the time constant of the integral term.
How would I get it
[image]it

Comment: I would evaluate the static error in steady-state conditions (when the output is stabilized). If the open-loop gain approaches infinity - which is not the case - this error is 0. In your application, depending on the return path, you can determine the final output level based the loop gain \$T\$. In the loop gain, there is the plant gain \$H\$ and the compensator gain \$G\$ hosting the PI compensator. From there, you should be able to determine the \$k_i\$ term.

Comment: Explain your design approach in more detail.

Comment: I'm having a cascaded loop, the oven heats, that's a PI controller, and there is a thermo couple outside the oven, and that's a P controller, currently in the above graph, it's the PI controller output, I have made Kp = 2048 and I get the response in the picture above, I would like to determine the time constant of the plant of the Ki term

Comment: Your model may be incomplete without T(amb.), Ria (thermal resistance inside Oven to ambient)  and thermal mass of oven, m and thermal resistance from mass of oven to T sensor ( latency)   }

Comment: Note dT/dt =0.77 ['C/s] is a function of Ki and input power but after 50% rise in T, slope decays due to external ambient difference and Pd loss.